# Import image in android studio, and generate different sizes

Tags: image, android-studio, assets, dpi, auto-generate

So in Android Studio, there is a tool called asset studio, which is nice.

I'm building my first game for Android and know there are different res folders for different DPI's.

You can let Android Studio generate the different images from one source image, using the Android Asset Studio.  But only for launcher icons, notifcation icons and actionbar icons. How can I do this for images i want to use in game?